# como pasar datos de un actity a otro en android

Tags: android, google-maps, activity, huawei-mobile-services, hms-core

Como pasar  datos de un activity a otro sin usar los editext o textview, algo como
activiy1 (dejar en pausa al precionar el boton opcion
-mapa
-opcion

acitvity2(Selecionar la opcion y enviar al activity 1)
-opcion a
-opcion b
-opcion c

-retomar la actividad 1 para poder aplicar la opcion - algun ejemplo que me puedan brindar

Answer (score 0):

Main Activity con un EditText y un TextView, permite escribir tu nombre en el EditText y lo envía a una segunda activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private final int REQ_COD = 0;
    private EditText etName;
    private TextView tvReply;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        tvReply = findViewById(R.id.tvReply);
        etName = findViewById(R.id.etName);
    }

    public void saludar(View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, saludo.class);
        intent.putExtra("name", etName.getText().toString());
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQ_COD);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent){
        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
            tvReply.setText(intent.getStringExtra("replyMsg"));
        }
    }

}
```

Segunda activity: Recibe tu nombre, muestra un saludo por pantalla y devuelve el valor a la activity anterior, donde se mostrará en el TextView:

```
public class saludo extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView tvGreeting;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_saludo);

        tvGreeting = findViewById(R.id.tvGreetings);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        tvGreeting.setText(getString(R.string.helloMsg, intent.getStringExtra("name")));
        Intent reply = new Intent();
        reply.putExtra("replyMsg", getString(R.string.helloMsg, intent.getStringExtra("name")));
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, reply);
        finish();
    }
}
```

Si quieres ver el código entero y descargar el programa puedes acceder a él en mi [repositorio de github de esa asignatura](https://github.com/Benito-B/mdm/tree/master/HolaMundo2)

Te sugiero que intentes mejorar el ejercicio añadiendo el paso de las variables a través de un Bundle